# Camera_calibration is frozen!

Tags: calibration, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i've this launch:

I run this launch while: roslaunch my_package_test prueba_gencam_cu_video1.launch

I calibrate the camera but when i click on Calibrate, the application is frozen and i don't know why :S.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31309/camera_calibration-is-frozen!/) by [alonsosjumper](https://answers.ros.org/users/2135/alonsosjumper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2012-04-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds similar to http://answers.ros.org/question/11252/prosilica-calibration-freezes-during-calibration

Calibration may take a while. Just be patient.

Which ROS distro are you running? The Calibrate step could be quite slow in Diamondback, but we made it much faster in Electric.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2012-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alonsosjumper](https://answers.ros.org/users/2135/alonsosjumper/) on 2012-04-11**:
Hello again! I'm using the 10.10 of Ubuntu. I've already gotten the calibration but after 5 times trying it. Thank you!